# ListFragment with AsyncTask not showing ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` which has an `AsyncTask` in it to write data to a remote store. I need to have a `ProgressDialog` show status while the data is being sent since this may take a considerable time depending on the number of files being stored remotely. I have done this successfully from an `Activity`, but I am having issues showing progress within the `ListFragment`s `AsyncTask`.

This is complicated by the fact that I need to show updates within the `doInBackground` method of the task, since that is where the major of the work is being done. That said, the `ProgressDialog` is not showing up at all even in the non-UI bound `onPreExecute()` method. Looking at other posts for `ProgressDialogs` I am using passing `getActivity()` to the ProgressDialog. Also this mechanism is working with several other `Activity` classes I am using else where, just not here. I am probably just missing something obvious so any help is appreciated.

Here is a code example - forgive me if it does not compile or has a mistake - I had to remove boatloads of code to boil it down to the problem at hand:

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    private void hideProgress() {
        if (mProgress != null) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            mProgress = null;
        }
    }

    private void showProgress(String message) {
        if (mProgress != null) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            mProgress = null;
        }
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, message, true, false);
    }

    protected void updateProgressMessage(String message) {
        if (mProgress != null && mProgress.isShowing()) {
            mProgress.setMessage(message);
        }
    }

    public syncForms() {
        new syncPendingFormsResultTask().execute();
    }
    private class syncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            hideProgress();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showProgress("Submitting Form...");
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
            onProgressUpdate("Uploading Form");
        }           

         @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
             String message = values[0];
             updateProgressMessage(message);
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             showProgress("Upload Complete...");
             hideProgress();
             }
         }  
    }
}
```

The `syncForms()` is the method called to initiate the task.

Comment: `onProgressUpdate("Uploading Form");`. Do not call `onProgressUpdate()` yourself. Use `publishProgress()`. Then later `onProgressUpdate()` will be executed on the main thread.

Comment: @greenapps Sounds good I will give that a try

Comment: Changing onProgressUpdate() to showProgress() in doInBackground did not work.